# Strange 'df' output + broken /etc/mtab

Tags: linux, raid, mount, arch-linux

I just installed Arch Linux on a server machine with a LSI hardware RAID 5.

During the installation, I created (and cfdisk properly reports) three partitions:

```
sda1 (/,     131G)
sda2 (/boot,   1G)
sda5 (swap,    4G)
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except that the df command is showing strange output:

```
Filesystem   1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs        131G        2.8G   121G     3%   /tmp
/dev/sda2    955M         50M   860M     6%   /boot
```

Note that at this point, /dev/sda2 isn't actually mounted... However, /dev/sda1 (my root partition) is missing, although it's definitely mounted. The readings for tmpfs would be correct if they were labeled "/dev/sda1".
Likewise, the mount command (and /etc/mtab) displays:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda2 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
```

Furthermore, I have a device sda3 in /dev/ which cfdisk doesn't know about.

In short:

- /dev/sda1 doesn't show up anywhere
- /dev/sda2 shows up without being mounted
- /dev/sda3 exists but doesn't show up in 'cfdisk' (and has never been created) or 'df'
- tmpfs is showing stats for /dev/sda1

This may be related to another issue I encounter during boot, see [Strange boot behaviour](https://serverfault.com/questions/394721/strange-boot-behaviour)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: sda3 is probably the extended partition, which it seems `cfdisk` omits from its listing.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely inside a "chroot" shell.  The installer has done something like this:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /target
chroot /target
```

The `chroot` command creates a shell where /target is /.  In that environment, the installer did `mount /boot`.  Since this environment is not the one that mounted /, it doesn't end up in `/etc/mtab` but `/boot` does.  I would assume however that if `/proc` is mounted in this environment, `/proc/mounts` might see the `/` mount.

Comment: Hey, you're right, `/proc/mounts` does see the `/` mount! However, I have rebooted the machine several times since installation, so I wouldn't expect to end up in a chrooted environment during normal boot. Any ideas?

Comment: During boot, I also noticed strange behaviour, please see http://serverfault.com/questions/394721/strange-boot-behaviour I'm pretty confident that those two issues are somehow related.

Comment: no, i wouldn't expect this to be the case during a normal boot,  I would "During the installation".  This is the case even when booting to the installed system?

Comment: Yes, it is. I boot the machine and it shows the behavior described above.