# Strange boot behaviour

Tags: linux, raid, boot, arch-linux

I have installed Arch Linux on a server machine with a LSI hardware RAID 5.

When the machine boots, it says:

```
:: Triggering uevents...
udevd[37]: worker [41] timeout, kill it

udevd[37]: seq 547 '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:01:07.0' killed

Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/sda1 ...
udevd[37]: worker [41] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)

ERROR: device '/dev/sda1' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device '/dev/sda1'.
You are being dropped to a recovery shell
    Type 'exit' to try and continue booting.


[   41.896810] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[   41.896877] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   41.897474] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[   41.897543] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   41.922993] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[   41.923048] sd 4:1:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through

[rootfs /]#
```

Now if I do type "exit", I get the following message:

```
Trying to continue (this will most likely fail) ...
:: mounting '/dev/sda1' on real root
:: running cleanup hook [udev]
INIT: version 2.88 booting

[and so on]
```

...and the machine boots nicely.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

udevd died because of PCI device PCI ID: 0000:01:07.0

Look here: http://igordcard.blogspot.com/2012/01/waiting-for-udev-events-to-be-processed.html